# ksystemsoundid_vibrate not working in iphone4 and ipad

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, ios-simulator, core-audio

In my application,I need vibration while wrong password is being entered by the user.

My device OS : iOS5

It is vibrating in iPhone3G but not vibrating in iPhone4 and iPad.

I have followed this steps:

1.Added the AudioToolbox framework to my Application.

1. In the file you intend to trigger a vibration, import the AudioToolbox header file:

   ```
         #import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
   ```
2. Finally, call the following line to make the device vibrate:

   ```
        AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
   ```

Is there anything, I missed.........
Thanks....

Comment: For one... the iPad can't vibrate.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying to make the vibration api works in my iphone5 and I found out that it won't work if the vibration settings have been off. (Goto System Settings \ Sounds => Vibrate on Ring.)

Answer (score 2):

I import  this framework `AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h` and call

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

try it.